# Would it make sense to specify complexity as O(fibonacci(n))?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Suppose you have an algorithm which processes at first N elements, then half of N, then quarter of N and so on. Would it make sense to characterize the running time of such an algorithm as O(fibonacci(n)), rather than, say O(n log n)? I want to use Fibonacci function because it looks more specific, on the other hand - it sounds controversial.

EDIT:

Sorry, it appears that it may be on its own an interesting question, but answers made me realize I needed something entirely different :)

Comment: `fib(n) = 2^n` ? Technically `n lg n` will be always below `2^n` so we can write, but I don't think there is a point in this case.

Comment: If the "process" step is of equal length then this algorithm will finish asymptotically in `log n` steps.

Comment: Why should `fibonnaci(n)` mean `n logn`?

Comment: `fibonacci(n)` is very close to `c * φ^n` where `c` and `φ` are constant, so I would understand `O(fibonacci(n))` to mean `O(φ^n)`. I see no relationship with either `n logn` or `n+n/2+n/4+...`

Comment: I think you're confusing Fibonacci numbers with geometric series.

Comment: @wvxvw: The number of operations in the algorithm you describe ("first [process] N elements, then half of N, then quarter of N and so on") is actually 2N-1, or O(2N), which is O(N).  To convince yourself, pick a number that's a power of 2 (e.g. 64) and draw a line segment representing this length.  Now draw another line segment slightly above it of length 32 (i.e. half the length) that starts at the same x position, then to the right of this second line draw a line of length 16, etc. By the time you get down to 1, only 1 unit from the bottom line will still be uncovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `O(nlogn)` and `O(fibonacci(n))` are both mathematically correct - because big O notation offer only asymptotic upper bound - this bound will NOT be tight.

Assuming each element you process is `O(1)` the complexity of **the function's complexity is actually `Theta(n)`**, since you actually have:

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 <= 2n
```

The above is correct because you actually have a [**geometric series**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with `q=1/2`, and for `n->infinity` you get sum of `2n`.

---

Note that since big O denotes set, then `O(n)` is a *subset* if `O(nlogn)`, and both are subsets of `O(fibonacci(n))` - **thus `O(n)` is the most informative and specific notation to use in this case.**

Answer (score 2):

N + 1/2 N + 1/4 N + 1/8 N + .... about 2 N :)
So the complexity is still O(N) if processing one item is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can write whatever you want as long as other people know what you mean.

That said, it's much much less confusing writing `O(n logn)` instead of `O(fibonacci(n))`, since not so many people will know what you mean with the second notation.

Moreover, fibonacci(n) can be easily thought as to mean the n-th element of the fibonacci succession.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it would not.**  The whole point of [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) in computer science is to provide an asymptotic limit of the cost of the algorithm, with some sloppiness.  Thus, for example, we ignore the hidden constants implied in almost every use of `O(x)`.  Similarly, we assume that every operation modeled in the analysis is of equal cost, except in rare, specific, circumstances (*e.g.*, arbitrary-precision arithmetic used in some cryptographic calculations).  **The goal is not precision, but rather a well-understood shared understanding.**